# Form - need to allow for apostrophes

Tags: forms, validation, asp-classic

I have a form written in classic ASP with some light client-side validation. Everything works well except for one thing - the form fails when there's an apostrophe. One of the fields may have apostrophes often (last name field - form would fail if user's last name was O'Brien, for example).

How do I fix this?

Comment: In what manner does it fail?  Do you see an error message, or (more likely), do you have a [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) problem?

Comment: I get the http 500 error on the page that inputs the data into the database - I've disabled http friendly errors, but still get that. I think it's the SQL injection problem, just not sure how to fix that.

Comment: as an FYI.. I am somewhat familiar with the   replace(request.form("LName"), "'", "''")   but unsure how to implement it... haven't found an example anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to examine your ASP code.  If you see any code that looks like

```
string SQL = 
  "SELECT user_id, first_name,last_name FROM users WHERE username = " 
  + myUserName;
```

where myUserName comes from the user, then you are definitely vulnerable.

The fix is NOT to try to escape the input (i.e., replace all "'" with "''") but to use a completely different method as outlined in this article on [SQL Injection and how to avoid it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/05/29/sql-injection-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx)

In a nutshell, try something like the following from the [bobby-tables](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp.html) site

```
String username = "joe.bloggs";
SqlCommand sqlQuery = new SqlCommand(
 "SELECT user_id, first_name,last_name FROM users WHERE username = ?username",  
  sqlConnection);
sqlQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("?username", username);
```

Comment: thanks so much! I ended up creating a function to remove the apostrophe before inputting the fields into the DB.. (before I saw your answer here). I'll test this out as well and see if I can implement it as I'm always trying to learn. Thanks SO Much for your help!